# MathWorks is written for Lego firmware V1.03, but Lego is up to V1.10

Tags: passwords, telnet, matlab, simulink

MathWorks (MATLAB and Simulink) is/are written for Lego firmware 1.03! (with no TelNet ID/passkey)  Versions 1.07 and 1.08 also do not require the ID/passkey.  Versions 1.09 and 1.10 do require an ID/passkey.  MathWorks software does not provide an ID/passkey and thus only works with V1.03, V1.07 or V1.08!  MathWorks does not work with the currently available V1.09 or V1.10 and Lego does not provide the old firmware (1.03, 1.07 or 1.08).  It should still exist somewhere.  In order for me to get it, it must be provided by the general public.

Can someone please post Lego firmware V1.03, V1.07 or V1.08?

**Addition**

StackExchange has several forums.  This is the Superuser forum.  There is also the Software Recommendations forum.  I am not sure which forum this post should be in.  However, it is in the Superuser forum and I will continue here to maintain the context chain.  However, would one of them be more appropriate than the other for creating a chain letter.

MathWorks is more likely to give this issue attention if it receives multiple requests.

I am asking for readers to send MathWorks a request to fix the "Lego EV3 firmware" issue.

**THANK YOU**

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. We don't post firmware. Please read our Help section to learn about superuser.com.

Comment: MathWorks is requesting that I use the Lego firmware that MathWorks is written for.  The request for that version of the Lego firmware must be appropriate somewhere.  Perhaps the Software Recommendations forum is more appropriate

Comment: Yes. That would be a great place to ask a question like this: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the special created fw 1.09D (Developer version) which allows Internet connection when using a LEGO provided ID/passkey. This fw version and documentation can be downloaded here: https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/developer-kits